# MPC4725 DAC outputting incorrect voltage

Tags: arduino, stm32, dac

I am trying to learn how to interface the MPC4725 DAC with my STM32 blue pill. I wrote this simple program (using the Arduino IDE) to output a DC voltage:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MCP4725.h>

Adafruit_MCP4725 dac;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dac.begin(0x60);
  dac.setVoltage(0, false);  
  pinMode(PA6, INPUT_ANALOG); //o/p of DAC is connected to pin A6
}

void loop()
{
  dac.setVoltage(1111, false);
  int read = analogRead(PA6);
  Serial.println(read);
  delay(1000);
}
```

And this is the schematic:

(Edit: The VCC of the DAC is connected to 3.3V and not 5V)

[image]

But the DAC constantly output 2055 (1.66V) instead of ((1111/4095)*3.3) = 0.895V.

[image]

I ran the [I2C device address finder](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/abdularbi17/how-to-scan-i2c-address-in-arduino-eaadda) program to check if the DAC is really connected to the STM32.

[image]

Clearly, the DAC is properly connected to the STM32. But for some reason, its constantly outputting 1.66V irrespective of the `dac.setVoltage(1111,false)` statement.

What's wrong?

Edit: I added external 10k pullup resistors to VCC(3.3V) and here's the output:

[image]

Its still random.

I added a 10k resistor between the o/p of the DAC to ground and I got even more random results:

[image]

Note, the zeros displayed are because of a small modification to the code:

```
bool check = dac.setVoltage(1111, false, 100000);
  int readit = analogRead(PA6);
  Serial.println(readit);
  Serial.println(check);
  delay(1000);
```

Comment: Does the output change at all when you write different values?

Comment: Where are the i2c pullup resistors? Arduino boards include these, others might not.

Comment: @Kartman I think the DAC breakout board has pull-up resistors in it. But I shall try again with external 10k pullups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#include <Adafruit_MCP4725.h>` library is probably incompatible with the STM32 blue pill, but the following method works (found [here](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-dac-tutorial-interfacing-mcp4725-dac)):

```
#include<Wire.h>

#define DAC 0x60

byte buffer1[3];
int data = 1000; //1.22V for Vcc = 3.3V

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  buffer1[0] = 0b01000000;            //Sets the buffer0 with control byte (010-Sets in Write mode)
  buffer1[1] = data >> 4;              //Puts the most significant bit values
  buffer1[2] = data << 4;              //Puts the Least significant bit values
  unsigned long t2;
  unsigned long t1 = micros();
  Wire.beginTransmission(DAC);         //Joins I2C bus with MCP4725 with 0x61 address
  
  Wire.write(buffer1[0]);            //Sends the control byte to I2C 
  Wire.write(buffer1[1]);            //Sends the MSB to I2C 
  Wire.write(buffer1[2]);            //Sends the LSB to I2C
  
  Wire.endTransmission();           //Ends the transmission
  t2 = micros();

  Serial.println(t2-t1);

  delay(200);
}
```

I wrote my own class for the same:

```
class DAC
{
  private:

    byte address;
    byte MSB;
    byte LSB;

  public:
  
    DAC(byte address = 0x60) //Default address is 0x60 
    {
      this->address = address;  
    }

    void setOutput(int data, byte saveData = 0x40)// Default saveData = false. Pass 0x60 for true.
    {
      MSB = data >> 4;
      LSB = data << 4;
      Wire.beginTransmission(address);
      Wire.write(saveData);
      Wire.write(MSB);
      Wire.write(LSB);
      Wire.endTransmission();
    }

    void setVoltage(float voltage, float reference = 3.3, byte saveData = 0x40) //Default 3.3V reference, saveData = false.
    {
      int data = ((voltage)/reference)*4096.0;
      this->setOutput(data, saveData);  
    }
};
```

And here is an example:

```
#include<Wire.h>

class DAC
{
  private:

    byte address;
    byte MSB;
    byte LSB;

  public:
  
    DAC(byte address = 0x60) //Default address is 0x60 
    {
      this->address = address;  
    }

    void setOutput(int data, byte saveData = 0x40)// Default saveData = false. Pass 0x60 for true.
    {
      MSB = data >> 4;
      LSB = data << 4;
      Wire.beginTransmission(address);
      Wire.write(saveData);
      Wire.write(MSB);
      Wire.write(LSB);
      Wire.endTransmission();
    }

    void setVoltage(float voltage, float reference = 3.3, byte saveData = 0x40) //Default 3.3V reference, saveData = false.
    {
      int data = ((voltage)/reference)*4096.0;
      this->setOutput(data, saveData);  
    }
};

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

DAC dac();
unsigned long t1, t2;

void loop() {
  t1 = micros();
  dac.setVoltage(1.17);
  t2 = micros();
  Serial.println(t2 - t1); //this is just to see how long it takes to write a voltage to the DAC
  delay(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2055 is suspiciously close to 2048, which is the DAC's default mid-scale output. So it sounds like the DAC isn't getting the commands at all.

- confirm this by writing different values and watching the output for any changes
- check your connections, especially i2c pull up resistors

The last thing to check is the following. The Adafruit library manipulates the i2c speed inside the setVoltage function: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MCP4725/blob/d04eeb23a3621f1718603a73448a53c8a79e4627/Adafruit_MCP4725.cpp#L69

Maybe 100 kHz works for the i2c scanner but 400 kHz is too much for your setup (insufficient pull up resistors). Try calling setVoltage(1111, false, 100000) with a lower speed to confirm that.

Also, setVoltage() returns a boolean success code, make sure that it's true.

You can also set this flag:

```
#define DEBUG_SERIAL Serial
```

at the start of your script to get more info from Adafruit's i2c coms.

Comment: I added 10k pullups, but it didnt work. Ive added the result of adding the pullups in the question

Comment: If setVoltage returns 0 (false) that means the I2C communication failed.

Comment: Can you try enabling the debug flag I just added to the answer?

Comment: It made no difference. Also, I just noticed that SCL and SDA are at 3.3V all the time, both with or without the 10k pullups. Its odd. The stm32 can find the DAC, but it cant write a voltage to it.

Comment: Also, the DAC breakout board has 4.7k pullups

Comment: You can try adding a small delay (eg. 50 ms) before each command (including in setup).

Comment: If that doesn't help, I would suggest writing your own code, first to check if you can get an ACK from the device address like in the i2c scanner, then adding a write command and see how/if it fails. Unfortunately the Adafruit library doesn't give you access to the i2c error codes.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. Take a look at my answer.